# Making folder names from URL php

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, dns

I have a system which will store certain files for various websites.

Some websites are shown as basic:

```
www . myrandomsite . com

www . yetanothersite . com /sublevel/

http: somefunky.sub . org
```

...and so forth.

I wanted to convert these to folder names in the safest and most sensible way.

---

What I have so far:

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', '-', 'www.yetanothersite.com/sublevel/');
```

returns: **string(32) "www-yetanothersite-com-sublevel-"**

---

This is hardly a pretty folder name though, but on the right track.

Given the diversity of domain name formats, I wanted to create the cleanest and simplest possible solution.

Need some advice.

Comment: Do the folder names have to be human-readable?

Comment: Sort of. I know humans will be seeing them when they navigate there. Also there will be a function that finds the folder by domain name, so it has to be consistent.

Comment: The solution may be somewhat OS dependent. Does this need to work on any OS or do you have a particular target in mind?

Comment: Would Using routing via Zend or htaccess help?

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following:**

```
$urls = array('www.myrandomsite.com', 'http://somefunky.sub.org', 'http://www.yetanothersite.com/sublevel/', 'http://stackoverflow.com/users///1401975/');

// PHP 5.3+ IS A MUST
$folders = preg_replace_callback('#(?<protocol>(https?|ftp)://)|(?<end>/+(?=$))|(?<replace>/+)#', function($m){
    if(isset($m['protocol'][1])){return '';}
    if(isset($m['end'][0])){return '';}
    return '-';
}, $urls);
print_r($folders);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => www.myrandomsite.com
    [1] => somefunky.sub.org
    [2] => www.yetanothersite.com-sublevel
    [3] => stackoverflow.com-users-1401975
)
```

**The script will:**

- remove the http, https, ftp protocol
- remove the last forward slash
- replace the rest of the forward slashes with a hyphen.